# how to update email admin with Custom Rule?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to edit the admin information using a Custom Rule, I want the admin to be able to reset her email when she edits her information but not to reset her email to others.

This is my Custom Rule `checkAdminEmailExist.php`, please correct it wherever there is a problem

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use App\Repositories\Interfaces\AdminRepositoryInterface;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class checkAdminEmailExist implements Rule
{
    public AdminRepositoryInterface $admin_repository;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->admin_repository = app()->make(AdminRepositoryInterface::class);
    }
    public function passes($attribute, $value):bool
    {
        if($value == Auth::user()->email) {
            return true;
        }
        if ($this->admin_repository->checkAdminEmailExist($value)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public function message():string
    {
        return 'The :attribute duplicate';
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I understand "Admin can reset her email address to any value except any other existing email in the database" is what you want - right?

Comment: Admin can reset her email address to any value except any other existing email in the database And can set his previous email again For example if the admin email is `admin @ gmail.com` when the admin edits his email he can set` admin @ gmail.com‍` again(Currently this does not happen because of the `checkAdminEmailExist()` function)

Comment: `admin@gamil.com‍` is an admin email has logged in and I want this to happen only to the person who logged in.

Comment: Then you don't need any custom validation rule. The built-in **unique** validation rule will suffice for your needs

Comment: But I want this to happen only when the admin edits their email

Comment: Normally any **users** data (table) would require the email to be unique whether admin or normal users. Anyway need to see the code for `checkAdminEmailExist()` to figure out the cause of issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage try to leverage **afterHook** like

```php
class UpdateUserRequest extends FormRequest
{    
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            /** Other rules **/
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        ];
    }
    /**
     * Configure the validator instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\Validator  $validator
     * @return void
     */
    public function withValidator($validator)
    {
        $validator->after(function ($validator) {
            $alreadyExists = DB::table('users')
                ->where('id', '<>', auth()->id())
                ->where('email', $this->email)
                ->exists();

            if (auth()->user()->isAdmin() && $alreadyExists) {
                $validator->errors()->add('email', 'The email address is already taken');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You will need to implement a **isAdmin()** method on **User** model to verify whether the user is an admin or not.

```php
//USer model
public function isAdmin()
{
    //Determine if the user has the role of admin
    return $this->hasRole('admin');

    // or if there's a is_admin boolean column on users table

    return $this->is_admin === true;
}
```

[Laravel Docs - Validation - After Validation Hook](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#after-validation-hook)